# didn't detecting any mobile phone that i connected to pc by using usb

Tags: usb, phone

whenever i connect any phone with my hp ay-15  503tx  model laptop, it didn't detecting the phone and not showing the storage options even though it charges the phone.
in my this lap i have both windows 10 and Ubuntu  16.04 OS
and this problem is also in windows 10 OS .

Comment: Then this can be a hardware problem. Micro USB port on your phone need to get replaced (that's what I think)

Comment: If it is an android phone, you might have to tell android how to connect. Connect the phone via usb and then swipe from top to bottom. Now you can choose how to connect e.g. only to charge or as mass storage. This is independent of the OS you are connecting to.

Comment: I tried with more than one android phone.still not connecting.When i drag down in phone.there is no notification of connection(that used to select mass storage or media device )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just today I had a similar issue. I used the USB cable (rather thin) of my previous phone, an Acer. Its also just started charging. Then I used the cable (thicker) supplied with my Galaxy S5 and immediately my phone was detected.

Comment: Thanks. When i tried to connect my lyf flame 1 phone with a diffrent USB cable,it works !!!!but till it didn't connecting my samsung s4  (gt i9505)